# How do I end a While Loop with 3 conditions

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, logical-operators

```c
while( num != 101 && num != 102 && num != 103 ){
    printf( "Enter number: " );
    scanf( "%d", &num );
}
```

I'm making a C program using Loops that accepts numbers from the user until the user inputs the numbers 101, 102, and 103. The above three conditions in while loop is working as an OR operator. If one of the three conditions is met, the while loop stops. What I need is that while loop should be stopped when the three conditions are met. I already tried to use || instead of && but the program just keeps looping. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but the `num != 101 && num != 102 && num != 103` condition can be negated either as `!(num != 101 && num != 102 && num != 103)` or as `num == 101 || num == 102 || num == 103`.

Comment: You need to change `&&` to `||` and `!=` to `==`. See [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: It's unclear what you want because you write that you want one of the conditions with "working as an OR operator" and that you want "the three conditions are met".  Please correct.

Answer (score 0):

```c
while( num == 101 && num == 102 && num == 103 ){
    printf( "Enter number: " );
    scanf( "%d", &num );
}
```

This is an infintive loop, because that is what you want. It "should be stopped when the three conditions are met".
Num could only justify one condidition. Num couln't be all three values (101 AND 102 AND 103) at the same time. Except you have a quantum computer.